# Como imprimir una matriz en java

Tags: java, matrices

estoy intentando imprimir una matriz de n filas por n columnas y que me la imprima de esta manera
000
000
000
pero al compilar me imprime la matriz de forma vertical 
asi
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner entrada = new Scanner (System.in);
    int f = entrada.nextInt();
    int c = entrada.nextInt();
    int matriz [][]= new int [f][c];
    for (int i = 0; i < f; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < c; j++) {
            System.out.println(matriz[i][j]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Tu problema es que estas usando `println` que incluye un salto de línea en cada 'impresión'.

Usa `print` en el for interior y `println` en el exterior para hacer el salto de línea

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner entrada = new Scanner (System.in);
    int f = entrada.nextInt();
    int f = entrada.nextInt();
    int c = entrada.nextInt();

    int matriz [][]= new int [f][c];

    for (int i = 0; i < f; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < c; j++) {
            System.out.print(matriz[i][j]);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```